# Uploadify Crashes Chrome's Flashplayer And Produces 'Ah, snap!' Screen

Tags: google-chrome, crash, uploadify

I'm going to call it The A.S.S. — The Ah, Snap! Screen.

Anyhow, I've got uploadify working well except for Chrome, which shows me The A.S.S. when I click the "Add Files" button. Anyone else run into this problem? I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to fix (or circumvent) it.

Here's the specs:

```
:: Mac

OSX 10.5.8
Chrome 8.0.552.237
jQuery 1.4.2
Uploadify 2.1.0


:: PC
Windows 7 Starter
Chrome 8.0.552.237
jQuery 1.4.2
Uploadify 2.1.0
```

Just to be clear, it isn't crashing when uploading a file, it doesn't even get that far. As soon as I click the "Add Files" button I get the ASS.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am having the same issue with 
Google Chrome 11.0.696.1 (Official Build 77414) dev on **Linux**

Comment: Same issue here with Chrome 10 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Try Using

```
jQuery(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
  jQuery('#file_upload').uploadify({

    ....your content....

 }); 
 }, 0);
 });
```

When directly loading the uploadify it will crash...This is a sideway method

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [issue](http://crbug.com/75583) being tracked.